# In Rails 3.1, in which folder should I place the jquery library?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to download the latest jquery library and use it in my Rails 3.1 app.  Into which folder should I place the jquery library?

I'm new to using jquery and relatively new to rails.

Comment: Rails 3.1 already includes jQuery by default.

Comment: Emily, can you make this the answer so I can accept it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3.1+ already includes jQuery by default. Rails depends on the `jquery-rails` gem which pulls in the jQuery library and the support libraries for UJS. See [The Rails 3.1 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html#railties) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The public folder would work. The assets folder works too, but since it's not compiled like coffee script, that isn't necessary. Also, unless you're modifying jQuery, you could just link it in from a CDN, See [Information about CDNs](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

Comment: linking from the CDN isn't a good idea if you ever do development without an internet connection.